# Exposing Custom Workload Metrics in Rancher

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, rancher

I have a small .net application which makes custom metrics available to Prometheus/Grafana via the "Custom Metrics" interface in Rancher. I can confirm that the metric data is arriving in Prometheus at the Project-level.

I'd really like to take this to the next level by surfacing some of this data in the "Workload Metrics" panel of the Workload display.

[image: Workload Metrics Panel]

**Is there a way to display custom metrics in the Workload Metrics panel in Rancher 2.x?**

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but the answer is NO. You need to create your own dashboard in Grafana. The in-built panels in the Rancher UI are predefined and not extendable for application metrics.